# How can we rename the primary key of a table in FluentMigrator?

Tags: c#, mysql, fluent-migrator

I need to rename the primary key of an existing table through `FluentMigrator` so an automapper can automatically detect the column.

For most columns, it's a simple `1)` delete any foreign key constraints on that column `2)` delete indices for that column and `3)` rename the column.  I have historically done this by:

```
Delete.ForeignKey("foreignkeyconstraint").OnTable("mytable");
Delete.Index("UserId").OnTable("mytable");
Rename.Column("UserId").OnTable("mytable").To("UserInfo_id");
```

However, this doesn't appear to work for primary keys, since I can't delete the automatically created index on that column.  What is the correct way to rename a primary key column with `FluentMigrator`?

Answer (score 7):

Use the following method call to rename your primary key (SQL Server)

```
Execute.Sql("EXEC sp_rename N'[Current_Primary_Key_Name]', '[New_Primary_Key_Name]', 'object';");
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work as long as it is not an identity (auto increment) column as well:

```
Delete.PrimaryKey("PRIMARY KEY").FromTable("mytable");
```

Comment: As of writing this will fail in Azure Database, if the primary key is the only clustered index on the table. I haven't found a workaround yet at this stage, and have just left the name of the primary key unchanged. This may not be a solution for the question, though.

Comment: One of the advantages of [labilbe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1195872/labilbe)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24406280/1488979) is `sp_rename` will handle that for you. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx).

Comment: @MichaelMinton Won't work for mysql though (as per original question)

Comment: @DanielLee True. Also worth noting that latest FluentMigrator's `Rename.Column` method will use `sp_rename` on MSSQL.